# How to store r results in tableau extract? We want to share the tableau workbook with users who do not have R or Rserver installed

Tags: r, tableau-api

There are users who do not have R installed on their machine. We want to share the tableau workbook with them. Is it possible to include the results from R script execution in the extract and use that data instead of live execution every time you open the workbook?

Comment: Tableau can run off of a flat file or an SQL interface, so any format like that, in which you can store your data will work. You just need to save the data frame as a csv or xlsx file,

Comment: You can also store the R output in a .RData file, and connect Tableau to that. Just as with a csv or xlsx file, you can then save an extract based on the file to improve load performance in Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau's R integration requires LIVE connection to R Server, therefore it **cannot store any data** that you calculate using R.

**SOLUTION:** Run R code and store the result to Rdata/CSV file that you can then directly connect to in Tableau.

Comment: We have many R calculations. It would be tough to keep one sheet with R connection and one with data from the CSV and maintain both. We already tried this approach it proved to be cumbersome. It would be great if Tableau would maintain the cache of the last R result and show it if the script is not run.

Comment: I agree that would be great! :) There are many tools online that allow automation of the process and even publishing the result of R script to permanent database which can be then easily accessed. I am also fan of "offline" processing due the performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Tableau workbook that uses as a connection excel files (one or many). If the excel files are generated with R, or with another automatic process, I embed those files with the Tableau workbook with extension .twbx, so I can share the report.

In order to embed the excel file/s with the Tableau Workbook I do the following:

1. Make sure you have in the same folder a Tableau workbook and the connection files. The Tableau workbook has extension .twb, and the connection files are, for instance, 'data_a.xlsx' and 'data_b.xlsx'.
2. Then I just zip the Tableau workbook with the data files with extension .twbx:

   `workbook_name <- 'charges'
    workbook_data <- c('data_a.xlsx', 'data_b.xlsx')
    zip(paste0(workbook_name, '.twbx'),
       files=c(workbook_data,
               paste0(workbook_name, '.twb'))
   )`

   3. Then you have a Tableau workbook with the data updated using R.